# Swift, segue information passed won't show

Tags: swift, xcode, class, segue

I'm trying to get some information to pass to another view controller. I did the segue and nothing is showing. I'm using an external class to organize the information. But I'm not sure why it's not working.

first view controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "toLocationVC" {

        let lVC = segue.destinationViewController as! LocationViewController

        lVC.locationImage?.image = locations[locationSelection].image;
        lVC.nameLabel?.text = locations[locationSelection].name;
        lVC.descriptionTextView?.text = locations[locationSelection].desc;

    }
```

second view:

```
var selectedLocation : Location?;


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    locationImage.image = selectedLocation!.image
    nameLabel.text = selectedLocation!.name
    descriptionTextView.text = selectedLocation!.desc

}
```

and this is the class Location:

```
class Location {

var image : UIImage
var name : String
private var description : String

var desc : String {
    return description + "\n\n\nThis Description and Images Provided by http://www.travel.usnews.com"
}

init(name : String, image : UIImage, description: String) {
    self.name = name;
    self.image = image;
    self.description = description;
   }
}
```

I've tried changing some of the code around, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Why do you put the code inside `didReceiveMemoryWarning`?

Comment: oh my bad, i wrote it wrong here.. its inside the viewdidload

Comment: it doesnt work.. it seems the information from the first view is not been passed

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you override the information you just set `prepareForSegue()` in your second view controller's `viewDidLoad()` method.

Just remove the following code from your `viewDidLoad()` and it should be working (if this is actually the correct segue and all data are set):

```
locationImage.image = selectedLocation!.image
nameLabel.text = selectedLocation!.name
descriptionTextView.text = selectedLocation!.desc
```

(And I got the feeling that the `selectedLocation` is `nil` (= not set) in the `viewDidLoad()`.)

Comment: my selectedLocation does say is nil

Comment: So have you removed the 3 lines from you `viewDidLoad()`?

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the segue as follows:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toLocationVC" {
        if let lVC = segue.destinationViewController as? LocationViewController {
            lVC.selectedLocation = locations[locationSelection]
        }
    }
```

Then set a breakpoint inside the `if let lVC = segue...{` block to see if it's ever executed. Step through the code and use the `po {variable name here}` command in the debugger to look into each variable.

You shouldn't be setting anything in the `viewDidLoad()` function any longer like Mischa suggested. So delete those assignments.

*If this answer doesn't help, I think you'll need to update your code listings to include more information. We can't see exactly where a lot of these variables are declared, or if the second view is the correct class.*